# Chained map/reduce in couchDB

Tags: couchdb

In couchDB, I have a set of items like the following (simplified for example's sake):

```
{_id: 1, date: "Jul 1", user: "user1"}
{_id: 2, date: "Jul 2", user: "user1"}
{_id: 3, date: "Jul 3", user: "user2"}
...etc...
```

I'd like to get a list of "most recent activity", sorted by date, with no duplicate user _ids. I can create a view with results like so:

```
{key: "July 3", _id: 3, user: "user2"}
{key: "July 2", _id: 2, user: "user1"}
{key: "July 1", _id: 1, user: "user1"}
```

but this contains duplicate entries for the same user. Or I can create a view that maps {key: user, value: date} and reduces to

```
{key: "user1", mostRecentDate: "July 2"}
{key: "user2", mostRecentDate: "July 3"}
```

but that isn't sorted by "most recent".

I know that the obvious solution - reducing over the results of another view isn't supported. [BigCouch](https://github.com/cloudant/bigcouch) supports chained map/reduce, but appears to be rather out of date / unsupported (last release 2012).

This seems like a rather common problem - what are some existing solutions (beyond "switch databases")?

Comment: There is [rcouch](https://github.com/rcouch/rcouch) which has view based _changes that allow you to do chained map reduce. Most of rcouch's good stuff is merged in couchdb 2.0 so if you can wait a bit you can do chained map reduce in couchdb by default. If you use cloudant it supports chanined map reduce natively

Comment: What about a view that maps [date, user]? If your date is sortable (like ISO 8601) and you query with descending=true, it should be sorted by most recent.

Comment: As with the first example, that would still contain duplicate entries per user. Moving it to the key instead of the value doesn't gain anything.

Comment: Hi @AkshatJiwanSharma I've been trying to find more info about the rcouch features in couchdb 2.0. I'm asking here as I imagine others will follow this path. Do you know if this feature has made it into the couchdb2.0-dev release? https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/03/18/cloudant-couchdb2dot0-sandbox/

Comment: Looking at the [Issue Tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1999) I could only find an old issue with no activity attached to it. Thanks to your link I also found [this doc about Barrel](https://docs.barrel-db.org/docs/using-the-view-changes#section-create-chained-map-reduce) (successor of rcouch apparently) but maybe there's better documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general idea of how you can do chained map reduce with couchdb 1.xxx. What we want is the ability to pass the the results of one map/reduce to another.

1. Subscribe to the _changes feed filtered by the view. This will give you a list of docs that will actually be emitted by the map function.
2. Next we need to call the view function for these filtered docs. It's simple since we can pass a list of keys to the view so we simply pass the keys and get the desired  result subset of the view.
3. Next we push this result either in a separate database or in the same one. We can use bulk inserts to perform the inserts  faster. If you use a separate database you can even reuse the `_id's` from the view results so the bulk updates would be a lot easier.
4. Within this database we define another view that sorts our results based on value.

   {key: "user1", mostRecentDate: "July 2"}
   {key: "user2", mostRecentDate: "July 3"}

since you have already gotten to this step all you need to do is create a view on `mostRecentDate` in the second database and you will get user activity sorted by date.

I hope you are using a dummy reduce though. One that returns null and is only used for `group=true`.

using a list function in step 4 can make your life easier. As bulk updates require the list of docs to be in the form `{"docs":[....]}` you can easily get it in one go with a list function.

Comment: This was August 2014. Does anybody know if we're any closer now in November/2015 to getting Chained Map Reduce in the open-source version of CouchDB?

Comment: greetings from the future! how are we doing in 2019?