# CouchDB - Leaderboard view with date key

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have a CouchDB database where each document represents one point scored by a particular player in a game at some particular time. I need to efficiently generate a leaderboard of players and their total scores, over arbitrary date ranges, sorted by score. It's easy enough to make a total score by date-player view, but I can't sort on the score since it's part of the reduced value and not the key.

Is there a way to do this in a single view? If not, is there any way to do it at all?

I thought of maybe using the score-by-date-player view to generate intermediate documents and using a second view to order those by score. But AFAIK, CouchDB doesn't have any convenient way to generate documents from views, or derive views from other views like that. And that would only work for a fixed date range anyway, not for arbitrary date ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Chained MapReduce" is not featured in Apache CouchDB 1.x. It is already [functional in Cloudant's fork](http://examples.cloudant.com/sales/_design/sales/index.html) and [scheduled for integration in Apache CouchDB 2.x](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-dev/201410.mbox/%3C20141008194806.D4FD618A90@urd.zones.apache.org%3E).

There are some ways to [implement it by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270276/chained-map-reduce-in-couchdb). However, if you just need to sort the leaderboard that would be an overkill.

Use MapReduce to select by date and group by user. And let the client sort by score.

Comment: There's over a million players

Comment: I see. Then, as I mentioned in my answer, you have 3 options: 1/ use Cloudant's fork, 2/ implement by hand the strategy described in the linked thread, 3/ wait for Apache CouchDB 2.0 (or more probably 2.1).

Comment: Thanks, that opens up some possibilities. Any thoughts on how to do arbitrary date ranges? Or at least a a fixed size sliding window? Even with chained views, I can't figure out how that would work.

Comment: Be sure that your date format alphabetical order is analog to date order. If so, you can `emit(<date>, <user>)` and reduce scores with `_sum`. Then, you can query it with `startkey=[<rangeBegin>]&endkey=[<rangeEnd>,{}]&group=true`.

Comment: Right, but what I can't figure out is how to order the players by their total score within the window. There's going to be 100k players in that window, so I need to index them somehow. I'm trying to come up with something better than rebuilding the entire index every time the window boundaries change.